# Access control variable in handlebar helper (Emberjs)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Can someone tell me why this is not working in the latest emberjs version:

```
{{#each link in breadcrumb}}
    <li>
        {{#link-to link.url}} {{link.name}} {{/link-to}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

Within the link-to helper the link.url does not get resolved. 
If i provide a hardcoded String value as parameter for the link-to helper it works fine.

The console says:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__ember1387120205571_meta' of undefined
```

**UPDATE:**

The testdata looks like this:

```
var breadcrumb = [ {name: 'Link1', url: 'link1'}, {name: 'Link2', url: 'link2'} ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the message says, `link.url`  has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid. Make sure that `link.url` exists, and link is an object with a non-empty url property not an array etc.

Comment: You were right, this was a typo error. But the problem is that the links are no not rendered at all. Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Hmm strange, I reproduced your problem in that fiddle and works http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/MUXTn/, can you reproduce that error with it?

Comment: Thank you, i found the error by comparing your example with mine. In my real application i had a dynamic segment within my route, which caused the error as it was not provided by my testdata.